# Is it possible to change file attributes external to Mathematica?

Tags: files-and-directories

Is it possible to change file attributes external to Mathematica, such as `DOC`, `JPG`, ...?

I'd like to change the `Creation Date` of a batch file from a folder with `DOC` files, for example.

**EDIT:**

I did a test based on some comment, but the modification only appears in the file properties and disappears in Windows Explorer.

```
SetFileDate["C:\\Users\\Leandro\\Desktop\\Teste\\2017-06-03 \
22.05.14.jpg", {1978, 1, 10, 00, 10, 20}, "Creation"]
```

[image]

Comment: This is more of a [Super User](https://superuser.com/) question.

Comment: @J.M. For kindness. Are you being a moderator could you migrate this question?

Comment: It might be better if you just ask the question without mention of *Mathematica* there, since this really has nothing to do with *Mathematica*.

Comment: @J.M. So it's best left here. thank you. I want to see this possibility with Mathematica

Comment: I don't believe *Mathematica* has a function to do this specifically so you would need to call an external command line utility like `attrib` under Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you want to use _Mathematica_ to change the creation date of a file: `SetFileDate["zot.bat", {2017, 5, 20, 1, 23, 45}, "Creation"]`.

Comment: Confirmed, the issue lies with the actual date: setting the date via `SetFileDate` older than 1980 causes windows to show a blank in the folder list creation date field.

Comment: here is the answer.. https://superuser.com/a/797493/185652